# Why are the leaves on my capsicum plant curling and turning brown?

Tags: diagnosis, diseases, leaves, capsicum-pubsecens

Does anyone have any idea what's happening to my capsicum plant and what I should do about it? There are no visible bugs on the leaves.

[image] 
[image]

Comment: Are you guys smokers of tobacco?  This looks like the beginning of mosaic virus from tobacco.  Tomatoes, peppers...and other same genus plants are very sensitive to mosaic virus...Just a thought.

Comment: I agree that it looks like it's probably some kind of virus (not necessarily tobacco mosaic virus, though).

Comment: No tobacco smoker in family .. But yes there are in neighbourhood .. How we can kill a virus ?

Answer (score 1):

Is it in vase or directly on ground?
If you have only one and it's in vase, I suggest to take it away, clean the roots, and replant it with new soil. Lack of magnesium or phosphorus could cause that.

Are there cultivation near you? It could be contamination by some pesticide or by some fungi like Phyllosticta.